# random seek in 7z single file archive

Tags: wikipedia, 7zip, compression, random-access

Is it possible to do random access (a lot of seeks) to very huge file, compressed by 7zip?

The original file is very huge (999gb xml) and I can't store it in unpacked format (i have no so much free space). So, if 7z format allows accessing to middle block without uncompressing all blocks before selected one, I can built an index of block beginning and corresponding original file offsets.

Header of my 7z archive is

```
37 7A BC AF 27 1C 00 02 28 99 F1 9D 4A 46 D7 EA  // 7z archive version 2;crc; n.hfr offset
00 00 00 00 44 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F4 56 CF 92  // n.hdr offset; n.hdr size=44. crc
00 1E 1B 48 A6 5B 0A 5A 5D DF 57 D8 58 1E E1 5F
71 BB C0 2D BD BF 5A 7C A2 B1 C7 AA B8 D0 F5 26
FD 09 33 6C 05 1E DF 71 C6 C5 BD C0 04 3A B6 29
```

UPDATE: 7z archiver says that this file has a single block of data, compressed with LZMA algorithm. Decompression speed on testing is 600 MB/s (of unpacked data), only one CPU core is used.

Comment: There is also interesting variant of `xz`, the vasi's `pixz`, which can pack files into several blocks and add index of streams to fast seek (usually for fast seek in `tar.xz`): https://github.com/vasi/pixz "*Pixz instead produces a collection of smaller blocks which makes random access to the original data possible. This is especially useful for large tarballs.*"

Answer (score 3):

It's technically possible, but if your question is "does the currently available binary 7zip command line tool allows that', the answer is unfortunately no.
The best it allows is to compress independantly each file into the archive, allowing the files to be retrieved directly.
But since what you want to compress is a single (huge) file, this trick will not work.

I'm afraid the only way is to chunk your file into small blocks, and to feed them to an LZMA encoder (included in LZMA SDK). Unfortunately that requires some programming skills.

Note : a technically inferior but trivial compression algorithm can be found here.
The main program does just what you are looking for : cut the source file into small blocks, and feed them one by one to a compressor (in this case, LZ4). The decoder then does the reverse operation. It can easily skip all the compressed blocks and go straight to the one you want to retrieve.
http://code.google.com/p/lz4/source/browse/trunk/lz4demo.c

Comment: lz4demo means i need to repack full huge file? Is compression level of lz4 of same order as 7zip? This huge file is packed by 7zip/lzma/xz because it is too huge; even in bz2 it is not a 4GB but 14 GB. Can you say anything about blocksize used from my file header?

Comment: 7zip doesn't "chunk" input file, so this is a single block, compressed using "sliding window" methodology. The problem you will face is that 7zip got an excellent compression ratio **because** it compressed your file as a single block. If you were to cut your file into small blocks and compress them one by one with 7zip, you would not get the same result. Unfortunately, the only way to get direct access to any portion of your file is first to cut it into small blocks. Hence the dilemna...

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

Concept: because you are basically reading only one file, index the .7z by block.

read the compressed file block by block, give each block a number and possibly an offset in the large file. scan for target item anchors in the data stream (eg. wikipedia article titles). For each anchor record save the blocknumber where the item began (that was maybe in the block before)

write the index to some kind of O(log n) store. For an access, retrieve the blocknumber and its offset, extract the block and find the item. the cost is bound to extraction of one block (or very few) and the string search in that block.

for this you have to read through the file once, but you can stream it and discard it after processing, so nothing hits the disk.

DARN: you basically postulated this in you question... it seems advantageous to read the question before answering...

Comment: sleeplessnerd, the question here is: "Does this 7z archive have many blocks or it has only one block?". I suggest it is only one block.

Comment: mmh 1min research reveals that a property of LZMA is that it supports very large dictionaries ( >1GB) so it really may be one coherent block.

Comment: Just checked. My file has single block. How can I find the dictionary size used in compression from the archive? Memory usage by 7zfm on testing was  25 MB.

Answer (score 1):

> 7z archiver says that this file has a single block of data, compressed with LZMA algorithm.

What was the 7z / xz command to find is it single compressed block or not? Will 7z create multiblock (multistream) archive when used with several threads?

> The original file is very huge (999gb xml)

The good news: wikipedia switched to multistream archives for its dumps (at least for enwiki): http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/

For example, most recent dump, http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20140502/ has multistream bzip2 (with separate index "offset:export_article_id:article_name"), and the 7z dump is stored in many sub-GB archives with ~3k (?) articles per archive:

> Articles, templates, media/file descriptions, and primary meta-pages, in multiple bz2 streams, 100 pages per stream
>
> ```
> enwiki-20140502-pages-articles-multistream.xml.bz2 10.8 GB
> enwiki-20140502-pages-articles-multistream-index.txt.bz2 150.3 MB
> ```
>
> All pages with complete edit history (.7z)
>
> ```
> enwiki-20140502-pages-meta-history1.xml-p000000010p000003263.7z 213.3 MB
> enwiki-20140502-pages-meta-history1.xml-p000003264p000005405.7z 194.5 MB
> enwiki-20140502-pages-meta-history1.xml-p000005406p000008209.7z 216.1 MB
> enwiki-20140502-pages-meta-history1.xml-p000008210p000010000.7z 158.3 MB
> enwiki-20140502-pages-meta-history2.xml-p000010001p000012717.7z 211.7 MB
>  .....
> enwiki-20140502-pages-meta-history27.xml-p041211418p042648840.7z 808.6 MB
> ```

I think, we can use bzip2 index to estimate article id even for 7z dumps, and then we just need the 7z archive with the right range (..p *first_id* p *last_id* .7z). `stub-meta-history.xml` may help too.

FAQ for dumps:
http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dumps/FAQ

Comment: The funny part is that bzip2 files can be index without multiple concatenated streams anyway since they are always in blocks that begin with markers.

Answer (score 1):

Only use:

```
7z e myfile_xml.7z -so | sed [something]
```

Example get line 7:

`7z e myfile_xml.7z -so | sed -n 7p`

Comment: Hello there. This will do full unpack (or unpack until SIGPIPE for very beginning), and My archive is very-very large, 999 of gigabytes in unpacked size of text (average line length of 20 or 30 utf-8 chars). Sometimes I want line 7, sometimes lines 10245-10345, sometimes lines 21453361643-21453361720. When I just want 1 million of lines near the end of archive, I don't want to unpack all 20000 million lines before (it will take half an hour). Some archive formats supports indexing to allow such type of accesses (build index once and use it for fast access).